# How to brand my company car online

Tags: designers, design-process, presentation-design, template-design

Wondering is there any sites where I can make an example embodiment of branding my company car.  Just to put some colours and logo on it,  yo how it will look like.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? A software showing you the contures of your car so that you can place on it logo, colors etc.  Maybe this is available for special cars ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is "mockup". A quick Google search gives a plethora of handy results: https://www.google.com/search?q=car+mockup